# How to connect SignalR to Azure's new made server?

Tags: signalr-hub

:)
 I'm developing a Xamarin chat application which I want to use SignalR and Azure servers for communication. I'm a nooby at servers. Look at this code:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://cforbeginners.com:901");
        var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
        chatHubProxy.On<string, int, string>("UpdateChatMessage", (message, color, username) =>
         {
             //Update chat message has been called from server
             int x = 9;

         });

        try
        {
            await hubConnection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Now this connection works and I  can connect to this cforbeginners server on port 901. But I wanted to have my own server so I made a virtual machine on Azure and connect it remotely to windows server with different endpoints like FTP and HTTPS and HTTP. My DNS address is something like XXXX.cloudapp.net and I can open the website and see the content. But when I replace it with http://cforbeginners.com:901 either with FTP port or https or http, it wouldn't work. What is the problem?